# XAMPP VM for Mac not showing uncaught Exceptions, returns 500 error

Tags: php, macos, exception, xampp

I am teaching a class and have a student who installed XAMPP for Mac using the [VM version](https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20170628.html). Everything works great, they're able to view their localhost and all their files, but when an uncaught exception should show up on the page, the page instead returns a 500 error.
"This Page isn't working, unable to handle request, HTTP ERROR 500". I don't have a Mac, so I can't troubleshoot it easily, but I assume there's a permissions setting, logging level, or server type (production vs sandbox) that I need to have them flip in order to see uncaught exceptions. Where would I find that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding this before your php script

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: It was display_errors, we modified them in php.ini from off to on!

Comment: OK cool. You can up vote my answer